More than 10,000 changes on source control in VSCode
I am a beginner to Git. I cloned a repo from GitHub I had created myself, now when I open it on VSCode it says:
The git repository at "c:\Users\my-user\Documents\my-directory" has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled.

I have tried the following:
C:\Users\my-user\Documents\my-directory> git rev-parse --show-top-level
C:/Users/my-user/Documents/my-directory

Then I've deleted the .git file in my directory, and made sure I didn't have any .git file above:
C:\Users\my-user\Documents\my-directory>git rev-parse --show-toplevel
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Afterwards I did either one of git init, or initializing the repo on VSCode itself, but it is still the same.
How can I get rid of all of these changes?

SOLUTION:
I actually created a virtual environment (.venv) in the folder from pip install -r requirements.txt, which is where all files come from (see all paths start with .venv\).
So I created a .gitignore file in my folder and added a single line: .venv/*. Solved.
